# Access PWA via IP address

Tags: c#, ssl, progressive-web-apps

I would like to develop a simple home automation web server and provide the UI in form of progressive web app (I am using Blazor.NET). Standard web app would not be sufficient because I need support for push notifications when the app is not opened. The server will be hosted loacally and accessed via internal network IP address or public IP address using port forwarding.

The problem is that PWA requires HTTPS with valid trusted certificate to work. But I am just not able to provide one like this. When debugging in Visual Studio, it generates a self-signed localhost certificate and I can access the app from the same machine without a problem. But I cannot make a second device trust a certificate of the server. I tried creating self signed certificate with both internal IP and public IP as common name, I have also tried registering to DDNS and providing the DDNS domain as common name, nothing works at all. Still getting NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID and the browser refuses to launch the PWA service worker.

I have absolutely no idea what to do. It seems to me like I have to be owner of a domain (probably pay for it and have absolutely no idea how I would do that) and certificate for this domain to make the bloody chrome trust it and launch that service worker.

In normal web app I would just use a random certificate and live with the insecure exclamation or even use HTTP. But PWA seems to require valid cert for some reason.

I can understand that security is important for public websites like eshops or social network but for my use scenario it is mainly a pain. I doubt anyone would make such an effort to turn lights on and off in my small house.

Do you have any idea how to solve/fix/get around this?

Comment: Consider hosting it on Azure App Service to get a free subdomain name and share a wildcard HTTPS certificate.

Comment: HTTPS is a core requirement. Never seen a workaround for anything else.